# How to know if a VS Project belongs to a WEB Application or Windows Application

Tags: c#

I´m using C# Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project class to retrieve specific information from a VS project file like the TargetFramework, AssemblyName...etc. But I'm unable to find the way or the property name to identify if the project is a Web Project. For a VS Project in framework 1.1 I'm using Xml parsing like this.

```
string path = "C:\\Test.csproj";
XElement root = XElement.Load(path);
var type = from el in root.Elements("CSHARP")
           select el.Attribute("ProjectType");
if (type.Count() > 0)
{
  //  Local or Web
  return((XAttribute)type.First()).Value);
}
```

I'll appreciate if someone could give me the name of the property or another suggestion to solve this problem.

Thanks in advance.

My full method code

```
public bool IsWeb(string path)
    {
        bool isWeb = false;
        try
        {

            Project project = new Project(path);

            // I dont know the name of the propety to identify if its a web project

            //string type = project.GetPropertyValue();
            //if (type.Equals("Web"))
            //{
            //    isWeb = true;
            //}

        }
        catch (InvalidProjectFileException)
        {
            //It's fw 1.1
            XElement root = XElement.Load(path);
            var type = from el in root.Elements("CSHARP")
                       select el.Attribute("ProjectType");

            if (type.Count() > 0)
            {
                if ((((XAttribute)type.First()).Value).Equals("Web"))
                {
                    isWeb = true;
                }
            }

        }
        return isWeb;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I went through a few project files.  In one of my mvc projects, I found this node in the PropertyGroup node `<MvcBuildViews>` it's definitely not an end-all answer to your question but it looks like more information than you were working with.

Comment: Does your project has <WebProjectProperties> tag?

Answer (score 0):

You can check if project type guid belongs to one of the [known types](http://www.codeproject.com/Reference/720512/List-of-Visual-Studio-Project-Type-GUIDs).